# I have issue after hosting my django app, working completely fine in ip address all the django style are working but not working in domain?

Tags: django, cross-domain, hosting, gunicorn

[See in IP address its working fine without any prblems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejy56.png)[See but in domain the styles are not working i don't know what to change and where i made a mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDErV.png)
Problem in domain hosting
Can someone check it and resolve my issue to make django app working flauless in domain

I have tried to change the Gunicorn confg and run in gunicorn but it doesnt make any changes so again i run in normal python runserver command.

Comment: We need to see your server config, and possibly DNS. Are you using nginx? Are you not wanting to serve your static files from cloud storage? Also it would be helpful to post your `settings.py`

Comment: can u tell me the main config and in setting.py things

Comment: Please post your settings.py for production and if you haven't used a server to host your app, I'll post an option. If you are using `docker`, which I feel like most should these days (or another containerization method) please post your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` or related files